# Integrating Flutter app facebook authentication with Keycloak service

Tags: java, facebook, flutter, facebook-login, keycloak

I have a **Flutter** app that is using **Keycloak** as it's authentication service.
Currently I only allow email+password login, and i would like to add option for the users to login using Facebook.

My question is how do i link the facebook login with my Keycloak service so that my service would manage the access tokens.

I found this very nice library for flutter facebook login: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

I'm using Java Spring web service proxy between the app and the Keycloak service.
I'm using `org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:6.0.1` library for the Keycloak client.

I would like to understand the flow of control that should take place so the user can login to his facebook account , and then my Keycloak service would manage it's access token so i can authenticate the user in my other services, which are all relying on the fact that Keycloak validates the access token.

Any suggestion would help , thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has a built in Facebook Identity Provider and makes it very easy to do this. Here is a link to Keycloak's Documentation which has a step by step on setting it up: 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#facebook

Here are the steps that are listed in the docs (copied and lightly modified because i'm not posting any pictures here).

*** FROM KEYCLOAK DOCS **

There are a number of steps you have to complete to be able to enable login with Facebook. First, go to the Identity Providers left menu item and select Facebook from the Add provider drop down list. This will bring you to the Add identity provider page.

You can’t click save yet, as you’ll need to obtain a Client ID and Client Secret from Facebook. One piece of data you’ll need from this page is the Redirect URI. You’ll have to provide that to Facebook when you register Keycloak as a client there, so copy this URI to your clipboard.

To enable login with Facebook you first have to create a project and a client in the Facebook Developer Console.

Once you’ve logged into the console there is a pull down menu in the top right corner of the screen that says My Apps. Select the Add a New App menu item.

Select a platform. Click the Skip and Create App ID button.

The email address and app category are required fields. Once you’re done with that, you will be brought to the dashboard for the application. Click the Settings left menu item.

Click on the + Add Platform button at the end of this page and select the Website icon. Copy and paste the Redirect URI from the Keycloak Add identity provider page into the Site URL of the Facebook Website settings block.

After this it is necessary to make the Facebook app public. Click App Review left menu item and switch button to "Yes".

You will need also to obtain the App ID and App Secret from this page so you can enter them into the Keycloak Add identity provider page. To obtain this click on the Dashboard left menu item and click on Show under App Secret. Go back to Keycloak and specify those items and finally save your Facebook Identity Provider.

One config option to note on the Add identity provider page for Facebook is the Default Scopes field. This field allows you to manually specify the scopes that users must authorize when authenticating with this provider. For a complete list of scopes, please take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api. By default, Keycloak uses the following scopes: email.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The link walks you through step by step on how to setup Facebook as an Identity Provider. Providing the link to the documentation ensures that if Keycloak updates this process that the solution is also updated.

Comment: I know, but please make it make sense even if you don't read the link

Comment: I've updated the answer with the relevant information on how the issue can be solved. I also highly recommend looking at Keycloak's docs to find the most up to date information.